# PowerPoint crashes while copypasting diagrams from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

Sorry for my English :-)

I have the following problem: while copypasting diagrams from Excel files to presentation, PowerPoint suddenly crushes. One of people I talked to said the problem was with .paste method, though I'm not sure about it. And I can't find any solution on the internet.

Function I use to paste graphs:

```
Function CopyGraphs(CurrentSlidePosition As Integer, CurrentWorkbook As Workbook, newPowerPoint As PowerPoint.Application) As Integer

Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet

For Each CurrentSheet In CurrentWorkbook.Worksheets
    CurrentSlidePosition = CurrentSlidePosition + 1
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Duplicate
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(2).MoveTo toPos:=CurrentSlidePosition
    CurrentSheet.ChartObjects(1).Copy
    newPowerPoint.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide CurrentSlidePosition
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlidePosition).Select
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlidePosition).Shapes("Graph").Select
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Windows(1).View.Paste
    newPowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Slides(CurrentSlidePosition).Shapes("Title").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Some text"
Next

CopyGraphs = CurrentSlidePosition

End Function
```

Here is the archive with files: http://yadi.sk/d/Sx38T0dKMGNoN
To execute it, you need to open Macro.xlsm and click the only button on the sheet :-)
PP crashes only on Windows. It works fine on Mac.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i have the same problem. I think that's something about links. If i paste as bitmap, powerpoint doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved crashing problem changing

```
<SLIDE>.Select
<VIEW>.Paste
```

to

```
<SLIDE>.Shapes.Paste
```

Comment: Yep, figured that out too! Although this way you have to align everything by coding it (.left and .top) instead of using PowerPoint templates for shapes (which is much easier).